# Automatically saving a big document that is fragmented over many webpages

Tags: download

I would like a copy of a certain manual which is spread over a large number of webpages like this [big document](http://www.state.gov/m/a/dir/regs/fam/).  I don't want to order a hardcopy and I don't want to have to click on every link to get the entire document.  What is the easiest way to put a copy of this manual on my hard disk?

Comment: You can try using wget --recursive.

Comment: If you use firefox, and don't mind `epub` or `mobi`, then I definitely recommend [GrabMyBooks](http://www.grabmybooks.com/) plugin.

Comment: I am trying `wget --recursive` now.  It seems there might potentially be an infinite loop.  I used `--level=99`, which might mitigate but is probably not the perfect solution to the loop problem.

Comment: @Darius, surly this is the best option and should be answer?

Comment: I'm running it again with `--level=9` instead of 99.  We shall see later if the result is reasonable.

Comment: @DaveRook I'm only on "maybe" on it since I had tried wget --recursive with partial success. Some sites it would go really well. Some sites would as broiyan said, goes infinite loop. Maybe the level limit will make a difference, but I have not experimented enough with it to give a proper definite answer

Comment: It was a PITA but with some trial and error, the right set of options will fetch a reasonable result in a reasonable amount of time.  Specifically, `--recursive --page-requisites --convert-links --timestamping --domains=www.state.gov --level=2 --accept htm,pdf --include /m/a/dir/regs/fam,/documents`.  Note that `accept` and `include` use a comma separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right set of options will fetch a reasonable result in a reasonable amount of time.  To arrive at this, there were a few trials.

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --convert-links --timestamping 
--domains=www.state.gov --level=2 --accept htm,pdf 
--include /m/a/dir/regs/fam,/documents
```

This cannot be a general solution because the choice to --accept certain file types is specific to the website.  The choice to --include certain trees is specific to the website.  Likewise the choice of --level is specific.

(@Darius may post an answer instead of a comment in which case I would consider selecting it.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a maybe answer (I'd only try if Darius's suggestion of `wget` doesn't work).... It also really depends on how lucky you are!

You can use something like http://www.httrack.com/ which will save the entire website to your hard drive.

The PDF pages you are talking about are predictable, in that they all live in the http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/ directory, therefore after you save the site, delete everything other than the `organization/` directory

The issue is there is no promise that it's only the pages you want live in that directory (for example, this directory *may* contain all the PDF's of the site, not just the ones you want). Depending on your needs, this may or may not suffice.